Access Denied Error while setting up Site Properties using CSOM in SharePoint online
I have a CSOM web job in place that creates a new SharePoint site and then sets its's properties using a Property bag.
Below is the code. The app which is being used for all the operations has Tenant Full Control permission and all of sudden we have started receiving Access Denied error.
Code:
try
{
    PropertyValues propertyvalues = ctx.Web.AllProperties;
    propertyvalues["SiteTemplate"] = "XYZ";
    ctx.Web.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}

Error:
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
This was all working fine till yesterday. The same piece of code is working fine on the Test tenant.
These are the steps I followed for initial troubleshooting.

Confirmed the app has tenant full control permission as I can access the site, get list, etc.
Granted the app Full Control access explicitly to the site still the error persists.

any help for resolving this would be great help as this is Production issue and has big business impact.

Did you find a solution to solve this problem?

The issue was happening because custom scripting was disabled for the tenant as Microsoft released an update.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/allow-or-prevent-custom-script
We extended the use of Custom Scripting on our tenant using a Powershell command.
Set-SPOTenant -DelayDenyAddAndCustomizePagesEnforcement $True

Also, it will be allowed only till November 2024.
